# view is not touchable after reappear

Tags: iphone, uiscrollview, uiimageview, subview

I have button to display scrollview. I have images under awesomeview. And the scroll having awesomeview for scrolling images. Then having myImageView8 for taking awesome view to center of the screen. When i click the scrollview images, the myImageView8 display the awesomeview in center of the screen. Then i recilck the button, scrollview is reappear. But myImageView8 is not touchable. After click scrollview images, the myImageView8 again display the awesome in center of the screen.

code:

```
scroll = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 420, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];
        scroll.pagingEnabled = YES;
        NSInteger numberOfViews = 3;
        for (int i = 0; i < numberOfViews; i++) {
          //  CGFloat xOrigin = i * self.view.frame.size.width;
           // awesomeView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(xOrigin, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];

            awesomeView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, self.view.frame.size.height)];

            awesomeView.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
            [scroll addSubview:awesomeView];

img = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];


            [img setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"img.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            // [overlayButton setFrame:CGRectMake(80, 420, 60, 30)];

            [img setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100,130)];

            [img addTarget:self action:@selector(img:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
            [img setTag:0];

            [awesomeView addSubview:img];



            img1 = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];


            [img1 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"sofa_s2.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            // [overlayButton setFrame:CGRectMake(80, 420, 60, 30)];

            [img1 setFrame:CGRectMake(110, 0, 100,130)];

            [img1 setTag:1];


              [img1 addTarget:self action:@selector(img1:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
            [awesomeView addSubview:img1];


             img2 = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
            [img2 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"sofa_s3.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            // [overlayButton setFrame:CGRectMake(80, 420, 60, 30)];

            [img2 setFrame:CGRectMake(210, 0, 100,130)];

            [img2 setTag:2];

            [img2 addTarget:self action:@selector(img2:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
            [awesomeView addSubview:img2];
}
        scroll.contentSize = CGSizeMake(self.view.frame.size.width * numberOfViews, self.view.frame.size.height);
        [self.view addSubview:scroll];
```

myImageView8 for display awesome to center of the screen:

```
 myImageView8=[[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 50, 320, self.view.frame.size.height)];
        [self.view addSubview:myImageView8];
        myImageView8.userInteractionEnabled=YES;

-(void)img:(id)sender{
 [myImageView8 addSubview:awesomeView];


}

-(void)img1:(id)sender{
 [myImageView8 addSubview:awesomeView];


}

-(void)img2:(id)sender{
 [myImageView8 addSubview:awesomeView];


}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you adding Images to your view, so your need to add touch event to your Image object:

[image]

> OR

Just enable the user interation programetically

> AND

Use the UIResponder methods touchesBegan, touchesMoved, touchesEnded etc to detect the touch on the image view:

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];

    if ([touch view] == yourImageView)
    {
            //add your code for image touch here 
    }

}
```

Comment: sorry can you see the edited question. I wrongly asked question.